# How to override the behavior of jQuery execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

On my WordPress page, there are two jQuery scripts which are as follows:

1)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.some_class').on('click',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
console.log('work 1');
//some custom work here
});
});
```

2)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.some_class').on('click',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
console.log('work 2');
//some custom work here
});
});
```

In the above two codes, you can see that on the same class I have done two different custom work but the first code is already present on the page and the second code is added on a certain php condition.

Now I want that if the second code is added then the first one should not be executed only the second one should be executed. But in my case the first one is executed it doesn't consider the second one at all.

I would also like to add that it's a WordPress page and the first code is added on a custom hook which comes before footer (somewhere at the middle of the page) and the second code is added on the wp_footer hook.

Can someone please help me with this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `off` function to disable any existing click handlers for the class when adding your second dynamic script:

```
$('.some_class').off('click');
```

Take a look here to learn more: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Be aware that the example I gave will unbind *all* click events from that class though, if your have other handlers bound it to too. To unbind only 1 handler you have to pass a reference to that original function too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global variable with ie. `var changed = 0;` where it's value shall be changed to 1 if second one is loaded onto page. And as it occurs globally, then first function wont fire with `if`.

```js
var changed = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if(changed == 0){
  $('.some_class').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('work 1');
    //some custom work here
  });
}
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  changed = 1;
  $('.some_class').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('work 2');
    //some custom work here
  });
});
```

Simple example of it working:

```js
var used = 0;

function one(){
  if(used == 0){
    alert("click");
  }
}
function two(){
  used = 1;
  one(); 
  alert("two");
}
```

```html
<input onClick="one();" type="button" value="Call one" />
<input onClick="two();" type="button" value="Call two" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the 'work' part of the handler to a new function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.some_class').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        do_custom_work();
    });
});

function do_custom_work() {
    //some custom work here
    console.log("1 default work");
}
```

then override this function in your optional code:

```
function do_custom_work() {
    console.log("2 overridden work");
}
```

Thus there's only one event handler (with preventDefault) and it will call `do_custom_work` which will be whichever file is loaded last (as described in your scenario).